# Multitape Turing machine with multiple non-blank tapes

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, turing-machines

A multitape Turing machine is defined to have input only appear on one tape, with the rest of the tapes blank.

Are there any formulations of a Turing machine that allow other tapes to be not blank? Why does the condition that the input only appears on one tape exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just simpler to describe the situation with a single input tape -- in particular, if you want to compare the power or efficiency of machines with differing number of tapes, it is convenient that the *format* of the inputs to all the machines are the same.

But it is not a particularly deep choice -- if you have input on one tape and want it spread across several, or have input on multiple tapes and want it combined into one, it is generally trivial to specify a machine that starts by rearranging the inputs as you wish.